# Paypal payment method not listed at checkout after enabling Paypal in Magento configuration

Tags: magento, paypal

I've setup Paypal in Configuration > Sales > Paypal a thousand times, but still not getting the Paypal option listed in the Payment methods on the Checkout process. And yes, I have filled out all the required info like the API credentials and such.

Also, I'm not getting any errors from Magento at all.

This is driving me crazy and it seems that no one (as far as I see) has gone through this situation.

Comment: offhand, try clearing the caches.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the default Magento theme or a custom one?

If you are using a custom theme then I would suggest temporarily switching to the default Magento one to see if the issue appears there.

If it doesn't then it's likely an issue with the theme rather than Magento.